# How should a random function be chosen to be run?

Tags: function, go, random, switch-statement

I have several functions and want to choose one randomly to run. I am using Go.

Currently I am using a switch statement. This does not feel ideal because if I want to add another function I have to increment the `rand.intn()` and add a new case. Removing a case is even worse because then I also have to decrement all cases after that.

```
switch rand.Intn(5) {
case 0:
    function1()
case 1:
    function2()
case 2:
    function3()
case 3:
    function4()
case 4:
    function5()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an array or slice of functions, use its length as the argument to rand.Intn.

```golang
var funcs = [...]func() {
    function1,
    function2,
    // ...
}

func main() {
    funcs[rand.Intn(len(funcs))]()
}
```

https://go.dev/play/p/62pjR4ogGqb